# MySQL select 1 result from multiple tables and MAX value from 1 table haveing multiple values

Tags: mysql, select, max, multiple-tables

I've been searching for a solution for this select problem, but couldn't find it.

I've got multiple tables from where I need to make one big select.
Unfortunatly, one table holds mulitple valid values.
But only the highest value is needed.

```
Table 1: customer (fields:  ID | customer_id | Name) 
values: (1, 1, Customer_name)
Table 2: address  (fields:  ID | customer_id | address_id | address | order_id)
values: (1, 1, 1, Streetname_Home, null) and (2, 1, 2, Streetname_Shipping, 2)
Table 3: order    (fields:  order_id | customer_id)
values: (2, 1)
```

This is an higly simplified example of the real situation and only for illustration the problem.

The problem is that the address table can hold 2 addresses (or more) per customer.
The select must select everything from the customer out of the customer table.
And than use the highest address_id from adress table.
And everything from the order table.

So what I got now is:

```
Select
customer.*, 
address.*, 
order.*
from
customer left join 
address on (customers.customers_id = address.customers_id) left join
order on (order.order_id = customer.order_id)
where order.ID = 1;
```

As there are 2 addresses in this example (home and shipping) I need the select only to use the address with the highest value of address_id.
As attached to that address is the order_id.

So based upon the address_id in need to get the order_id to link the select to the order table.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Change WHERE to AND - and order is a reserved word, so you'll need to do something about that too

Comment: Please give more sample data. Go to SQLFiddle.com and load up some sample data. Also provide a sample output. (You could just give us a list of the primary keys per row in the result set you expect.) Your address table implementation seems strange. I dealt with schemas where the order table has a foreign key to an addresses table (i.e., one address can be associated with one or more orders.) Your data model seems to be the reverse - one order can be associated with one or more addresses.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the replies, as the project I'm working on, consist of many more tables, I tried to keep it simple.
So I do understand that the table structures aren't logical.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c658c/4/0
Based on the Ordinal column, I need to get the needthis_id to further select data.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `address` table's `id` field is its primary key

```
SELECT customer.*, 
    address.*, 
    order.*
FROM customer
LEFT JOIN (SELECT customers_id, MAX(id) AS address_id
           FROM address
           GROUP BY customers_id) AS max_address
  ON customer.customers_id = max_address.customers_id
LEFT JOIN address 
  ON max_address.address_id = address.id
LEFT JOIN `order`
  ON (order.customers_id = customer.customers_id)
WHERE order.ID = 1;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply.

I still can't get it to work.
I think my example misled you in given solution.

So I changed the posting a little bit.
I need the select to have the highest address.address_id to join the address table upon the orders table on address.orders_id.